# Compiling a code with mysql_config and pkg-config

Tags: mysql, c, gtk, pkg-config

recently I've been learning how to program GTK+ applications and MySQL in C programming language.

I wanted to try writing a program with both of those libs at once, I've done it but I can't compile it...

When I compile a program which uses MySQL I do this:

```
    gcc exa_7.c -o exa_7 -std=c99  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

and when I compile GTK+ application I do this:

```
    gcc -o test_5 test_5.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

I can't write both of them, I mean `pkg-config` and `mysql_config` at once, because compiler won't accept it. I've been trying to find some makefile scripts but haven't found anything usefull. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Generally, you should be able to use both. So what error do you get ?

Comment: `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--cflags’` and much more, I won't copy all the message because it's all in polish. The essential is: it lists the libs like `gcc: error: [-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:` one after another and says "There is no such file or directory`

I don't know how to write both `pkg-config` and `mysql_config` in this command syntax

Comment: That means you're missing a whitespace somewhere, or have some error in the backticks (*\`*) somewhere. Update your question where you paste in the *EXACT* command you use to compile.

Comment: sure, I've been trying something like this

gcc app_0.c -o app_0 `mysql_config pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`

and like this

gcc app_0.c -o app_0 `pkg-config mysql_config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`

and like this

gcc app_0.c -o app_0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 mysql_config`

none of them works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to do this:

```
gcc exa_7.c -o exa_7 -std=c99  `mysql_config --cflags --libs` `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

If the backticks are causing you problems, you can run the programs using $() instead:

```
gcc exa_7.c -o exa_7 -std=c99  $(mysql_config --cflags --libs) $(pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0)
```

Comment: Finally... There is an issue. I though it was ok because there are no more syntax error of the command, but there is something wrong. Please have a look.

When I compile just mysql program with: gcc exa_4.c -o exa_4 -std=c99  `mysql_config --cflags --libs` it works just fine, but when I compile mixed mysql gtk program with your command I get this kind of error:
/usr/include/mysql/my_global.h:971:1: error: unknown type name ‘ulong’
In file included from /usr/include/mysql/my_global.h:1039:0,
             from app_0.c:7:
/usr/include/mysql/my_dbug.h:37:3: error: unknown type name ‘uint’ etc...

Comment: I just solved it :) I moved `#include <my_global.h>` and `#include <mysql.h>` on the beginning of the code, the way that is the first inclunde, and now it works fine :) thanks again!